# What's wrong with this quicksort?

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, quicksort

QuickSort. Code is written in pure C. Whats wrong with this algo implementation?

```
void quick_sort(void *base, size_t num, size_t size, int (*comp)(const void*, const void*)) {
    unsigned int i = 0, j = num-1;
    int rpos = rand() % num;
    do {
        while(comp((char*)base + size*i, (char*)base + rpos*size) < 0) i++;
        while(comp((char*)base + size*j, (char*)base + rpos*size) > 0) j--;
        if (i <= j) swap((char*)base + size*i++, (char*)base + size*j--, size);
    } while (i <= j);
    if (i < num) quick_sort((char*)base, j, size, comp);
    if (j > 0) quick_sort((char*)base + size*i, num - i, size, comp);
}
```

It falls into infinite recursion.

Comment: You can't do pointer arithmetic on `void *` in pure C; you can only do it like that in GNU C.  Strictly, you should convert `base` to `char *` or thereabouts before adding offsets to it.  Also, you're accessing out of bounds with `j = num`...the last element of the array is (more or less) `base[num-1]`.

Comment: Ok, but it don't solve this problem.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized.

Comment: Your while loops need to stop before `i` is equal to `num` or `j` is equal to `-1`.  It is probably not necessary to swap a row with itself if `i == j`.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a service for debugging your buggy code. You can debug it yourself: find a case that fails. Write down on paper **everything** you believe this program should do for that case. Now step through the program in the debugger. When it does something not on your list, that's the bug.

Answer (score 1):

There should be if(i<=j) swap and do . . . while(i<=j) not just (i < j ). And you need to increase i and decrease j after swap too.

There http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Sorting/Quicksort has sample code really easy to understand :)

Comment: Im not sure why you would need to do the swap on equality of i and j, but it looks like the loop termination is too early and is needing the  while ((i<=j)

Comment: `if(i<=j) swap` doesn't make sense - it simply swaps mid element with itself.

Comment: you still need it to increase i and decrease j or it still might be loop infinitely.

Comment: it isn't work anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If nothing else, it looks like you've got some off-by-one errors.

If `num` is supposed to be the number of elements to sort, then the array indices should go from `0` to `num-1`.  By starting with `j = num` and comparing the value at `base + size*j`, you're consistently stepping outside your array bounds.

Also, try swapping your pivot element to either the beginning or end of your sorting region before doing the sweep; this will keep it from being stepped on...

Comment: Yep, it's an error, but it also crashes after fixing it